# PHP MySQL Query returns nothing, Same Query in phpmyadmin is correct

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I know this already exists, I've searched before. But the given solution doesn't work for me.

I have the following in my *get.php*:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM cars WHERE Name='$Name' and Year='$Year'";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Found Stuff";
} else {
    echo "Didnt find: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
```

However, it always displays that it didn't find anything. Copying then the query from this return, pasting it into phpmyadmin, gives the wanted result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[mysqli_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)**

> Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or
>   EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For
>   other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE. As per this
>   condition

```
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
```

You get mysqli_result from your query and this is not equal to TRUE and you always goes into error condition

Use **[num_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php)** to check your query return result or not as

```
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$row_cnt = $result->num_rows;
if ($row_cnt > 0) {
    echo "Found Stuff";
} else {
    echo "Didnt find: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```